# twitter bootstrap navbar not expanding correctly when clicking the button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have made my navbar using css bootstrap and it works correctly when the device can contain the whole navbar, but if it can't a button shows up and when you click it the menu appears, i am having some issues with the menu, http://red-sec.net is an example of it, if you go to that webpage and resize your screen you will see the button, click it and see what happens.
this is the code for my navbar:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      <a href="http://red-sec.net" class="navbar-brand logo"><span style="display:none;">Hidden Text</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://announcements.red-sec.net">Announcements</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://forum.red-sec.net">Forum</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://news.red-sec.net">News</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://donate.red-sec.net">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net/signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net/Login.php">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

in case you are not able to view it here is an image of what happens
http://prntscr.com/e0klbu

here is the styling for the logo class:

```
.logo{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:150px;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:0;
    height:30px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    background:url('../redsec.png');
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

style.css row 27

.nav element has a rule with

```
height: 70px !important;
```

Remove this and the whole menu will show.

Comment: nevermind it did, thanks lol i had to clear cache, i will accept your answer, but is there another way to make the navbar more in height ??

Comment: you can use min-height or add some padding (if you want more black)

Comment: oh yeah thanks man appreciate it ill accept the answer in 4 minutes

Comment: accepted your answer :) thanks, do you any ideas with what to do with the background ? designing is not my strong suite

Comment: i have a new question u might be able to help ? check it on my profile please. if u help ill choose u as the answer